# What ubuntu version should install for a Toshiba Satellite l305d (64 kb)

Tags: software-recommendation, versions, distro-recommendation

I bought a Toshiba Satellite L305D-SP6805R, It comes with an ATI Radeon HD 3100 graphics card, an AMD Athlon X2 64-bits processor.

I’ve tried to install in Ubuntu and Fedora, but all of them have given me the same problem: the computer reaches 105ºC, the highest temperature allowed by it before shutting itself off to avoid damage. The problem? The fan is not correctly managed/detected by the kernel, and it can’t be managed by the user either.

I found a solution right here: http://yeiacatl.wordpress.com/2010/09/02/installing-linux-in-a-toshiba-satellite-l305d-with-temperature-problems/.  But they recommended to use ubuntu 9.10 and it is not longer supported. So my laptop is a little old and I wanted to know what distro should I install.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not reset or update BIOS as suggested in the article you linked to?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to install an older kernel version with Ubuntu and then put it on hold to avoid updates. I never tried it myself, but looking at [this guide](http://www.thanhsiang.org/faqing/node/129) it seems fairly easy. But mind that by going back to an older version of the kernel you are forgoing automatic updates.

Comment: Even if it is not longer supported?????

Comment: no, no way to do it, I can not even run "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras"

Comment: could I do it with a supported distro???????

Comment: It is unlikely for someone to still maintain repos or packages for such an old kernel, so while it is probably feasible to install it, you'll likely end up compiling most programmes you need.

Answer (score 0):

Im dealing with the same issue, trying to find a fix for the latest ubuntu. It's so much fasyer than windows even with the Live CD.

Have you tried setting low-only in BIOS to boot into Ubuntu and install lm-sensors and ubuntu-restricted-extras?

I'm at that step and will be updating Bios next to see if it helps. May have to force acpi and few more things in GRUB.